# expect multiple pass & multiple hosts

Tags: bash, expect

I need a script with expect, to connect & execute differents commands.
The problem it's the server have differents passwords and when I try put the second pass (after the fisrt error of login) doesn't work
The list of servers are inside of servers file and the passwords inside of the script

```
#!/bin/bash

user=probe
pass1=pass1$
pass2=pass2$
command="cat /etc/init.d/probe"
command2="exit"
for i in `cat servers` ;
do
        /usr/bin/expect <<EOF
        set timeout -1
        log_user 1
        #exp_internal 1
        spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t  $user@$i
        expect {
        "*?assword:*" {
        send "$pass1\r"
        expect "(.*)\r"
        send "$pass2\r"
        expect "(.*)\r"
        send "$command\r"
        expect "*]$ "
        send "$command2\r"
        expect "*]$ "
        interact
        }
        }
EOF
done
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: @pynexj, are you going to keep spamming every expect question? Why don't you provide an actual answer showing it in action?

Comment: @runouri, can you expect something more specific than `(.*)`? In fact, since the default `expect` mode is `-glob`, you're looking for that as a **glob** pattern, which would match a literal open parenthesis, a literal dot, any number of characters followed by a literal close parenthesis.

Comment: I'd suggest using `expect -d <<EOF` to get expect to output debugging information  so you can see how your patterns get matched (or not)

Comment: @glennjackman - not every expect Q i believe. (need to confirm). i'm more interested in Qs tagged with both expect and bash/shell. :)